# Why does this WPDB code throw an empty WPDB error?

Tags: wpdb

I'm writing a [feed reader plugin for wordpress](http://mattkatz.github.com/Wordprss). I'm seeing a DB error that I can't figure out.
First I [create a table called user_entries](https://github.com/mattkatz/Wordprss/blob/user_feeds/install_upgrade.php#L51).
Then I put a [sample entry into that table](https://github.com/mattkatz/Wordprss/blob/user_feeds/install_upgrade.php#L119).
When [I try to delete an entry](https://github.com/mattkatz/Wordprss/blob/user_feeds/backend.php#L116), I get a very strange error in my debug log.  There are no foreign keys yet, no indices on the db, etc.

> [02-May-2012 11:21:52] WordPress database error  for query 
>         DELETE 
>         FROM wp_wprss_user_entries
>         WHERE owner_uid = 2 
>         AND feed_id = 2; made by do_action, call_user_func_array, wprss_unsubscribe_feed, WprssFeeds->remove

So what is the error?  It's just blank in there. This doesn't look like complicated SQL and it works fine in the phpmyadmin query window. I'm not sure what to do for a next step now, and I'd like folks to be able to unsubscribe from a feed!

Comment: Echo that query and run it directly on your db table via PHPMyAdmin...

Comment: Actually did that - the query wasn't actually throwing an error or having a problem.  See stephan's answer...

Comment: Cool... glad you found a solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've linked to above:

```
    //$sql set to raw SQL statement
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$feed_id);

    if($wpdb->query($sql)){
      $resp->uf_error = $wpdb->print_error();
    }
```

So if there *isn't*, an error you try displaying the 'error' with `$wpdb->print_error()`. Also`$wpdb->print_error()` doesn't **return** an error, it **prints** it.

It's (probably) the printing of that non-error that is causing an error in your second database query, the one for which an error is logged.

**Side note:** take a look at the [`wpdb` class.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) There are methods in there that handle INSERT/UPDATE queries so you don't have to do them manually.